# How do I get rid of these "Formatting" lines?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

My Word documents currently have these dotted boxes that show where the paragraphs/ boxes are. Is there a way to turn it off? I'm currently using a Macbook Air.

[image: Screen Shot of what my Word looks like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's entirely the same path to the setting because I'm on Windows:

Go to File > Options > Advanced and in the 'Show document content' section is a checkbox named 'Show text boundaries', turn that off and the boxes should be gone.

Comment: Thank you! I finally got the lines to go away! For anyone else that may be having this problem, the path for mac is: **Word** > **Preferences** > **View** the "Show text boundaries" option is in the "Show in Document" section.